# Did Abrams make any Star Trek references in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, the-force-awakens, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-2009

J.J.Abrams directed *Star Trek (2009)* and *Into Darkness* before doing *Star Wars Episode 7*. Are there any references between the two films? I'm using a loose, broad definition of reference for this question, so this includes any overlap in cast and crew, plot, as well as your usual "easter-egg" references.

Comment: It may interest you to know that there were [119 common cast & crew members](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0796366,tt2488496) who worked on both Star Trek (2009) and The Force Awakens (2015).  You can probably add another fifty if you include Into Darkness.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.hitfix.com/news/jj-abrams-got-his-favorite-easter-egg-into-star-wars-the-force-awakens) count?

Comment: @RogueJedi hmm, I get I just thought there'd be more references, but I know that's not your fault, that's how Abrams made the film. +1 from me btw, and I'll probably accept it soon. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes.

[Unkar Plutt](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0526630/) is played by Simon Pegg, who portrays Scotty in the new *Star Trek* films.

[image: Simon Pegg, *Star Wars*]

Additionally, as @Valorum mentioned, [over a hundred cast and crew](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0796366,tt2488496) worked on both movies.

[slashfilm.com](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awakens-easter-eggs/3/) believes that there may be something else linking the films (as well as some other works that Abrams is associated with).

> JJ Abrams has often included a frozen drink called Slusho in many of his tv shows and movies, including Cloverfield, Alias and the Star Trek films. When asked if the cult Japanese frozen slushy would appear in The Force Awakens, Abrams refused to answer — which makes us believe its probably in there somewhere in the background, most possibly in the sequence in Maz’s Castle.